# Would like to have Windows back

Tags: windows, mbr

So i tried to install Ubuntu, it wasnt going wery well, so I decided to stop it. I manually stopped my computer, booted it up and I get "MBR Error 1" Insert floppy.

I launched my BIOS panel, and i do not have Windows boot manager anymore.
I tried to install Ubuntu on my external HDD, though i needed to reformat and stuff, could i have picked the wrong HDD? Could i have picked the one with windows on it?

And how can i fix this problem, its kinda annoying, can't use my PC.
I use windows 7.

Comment: Please add: Is your Windows 7 64bit or 32bit? Which Ubuntu version did you install? Does your Computer use BIOS or UEFI?

Answer (score 2):

If it is just the MBR, you can install a Windows equivalent boot loader from most Linux repairCD or your Ubuntu installer.

How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You can repair many boot issues with this or 'Create BootInfo' report (Other Options) & post the link it creates, so we can see your exact configuration and diagnose advanced problems.
LighterWeight (Lubuntu based) Boot-RepairCD

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

And manually you can install the lilo boot loader, not all of lilo.
Restore basic windows boot loader - universe enabled if error on lilo not found
Simply open Synaptic and Settings > Repositories and tick the box against the Universe repo in the Ubuntu Software tab. Close that window and click on reload before installing lilo with Synaptic or command line.

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

May show error messages about the rest of lilo missing, ignore, we just want MBR with bootloader.

A few BIOS have settings that lock MBR. You may want to check that is not your issue. May be called bitlocker, virus protection, secuity, or locked boot sector.

Answer (score 1):

You can install  or bring back your Windows MBR by following steps. Here are the two solutions that have have worked for me.

Boot Linux and make sure you’ve a working Internet connection and type the following on the terminal.

**1. Solution**

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
```

If the package got installed, use the following command to write the MBR:

```
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

**2. Solution**

```
sudo apt-get install mbr
```

If the package got installed use following to write the MBR.

```
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda
```

***Common for both***

***Replace sda if you want to install the MBR to a different drive. Do not put `sda1`,`sda2`,  or `sda3`. Just put it as `sda` for the hard disk. Finally reboot and your Windows should boot.***

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu won't repair your Windows7 original MBR configuration. For that you need the  Windows 7 Repair CD.

After a simple google, [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html) is what I found. You should be fine following it.